# Rotate picture then then set the properties after the rotation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a picture uploaded then rotated then set properties.

This gets my picture uploaded to the properties I want, but not rotated

```
Sub tyh()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
      Filename:="C:\Users\dovi.dovi-PC\Desktop\ads bh\IMG-7042.jpg", _
      LinkToFile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
      Left:=1200, Top:=604, Width:=350, Height:=604
End Sub
```

This gets the picture uploaded set the properties then rotates the picture

```
Sub tyh()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
      Filename:="C:\Users\dovi.dovi-PC\Desktop\ads bh\IMG-7042.jpg", _
      LinkToFile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
      Left:=1200, Top:=604, Width:=350, Height:=604
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Rotation = 90
End Sub
```

The problem is that I need the picture rotated first (because it's not a square) then set the properties but whereever I try putting.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count).Rotation = 90
```

before the properties I get

> Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

or

> Syntax Error

Comment: Are you trying to rotate a picture before you've added it to the sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rotate a picture before you add it.

So first add it …

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
  Filename:="C:\Users\pcr\Pictures\IMG_20180703_150535.jpg", _
  LinkToFile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoCTrue, _
  Left:=1200, Top:=604, Width:=350, Height:=604
```

Then rotate it and give it the desired position (and/or resize):

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
    .Rotation = 90
    .Left = 1200
    .Top = 604
End With
```